# How do I get an element to fill the remaining vertical area of its containing div?

Tags: html, css, dart

I want the "Go!" button to fill the remaining vertical area within each section. Where a section is defined as the area from the blue text to the light grey border at the bottom of each section.

Right now, it hangs out in the top right corner.

As you can see, each section is variable in size, so I can't just use a "static" solution. Furthermore, in the future, I may be dynamically changing the content within each section, which would cause further reflows.

I am using twitter bootstrap and Dart, the code below is the Dart html I use for the rendering of each section.

[image: My problem, the go does not fill the vertical area of its parent]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>x-search-result</title>
    <link rel="components" href="packages/widget/components/collapse.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <element name="x-search-result" constructor="SearchResultComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div class="row-fluid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
          <span class="span10">
            <div class="accordion-heading" >
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">{{name}}</a>
            </div>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
          </span>
          <button class="btn span2" style="height:100%;" on-click="switchToCardView()">Go!</button>  
        </div>
        <script type="application/dart" src="xsearchresult.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide some css as well?

Comment: I am using no css other than twitter bootstrap, all other css is inline style. (Ahh, don't yell at me! I'm sorry!)

Comment: So those who have never used Bootstrap should download it first? :/ Could you not just give button a height of 100%?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap in fixed width mode or responsive mode?

Comment: Marc - I am using fixed mode, although each row is fluid. pzin - I actually tried the 100% thing (it is in the code), no dice.

Comment: @StephenCagle I'll be back later... dinner time here.  I bookmarked your question.

Comment: Thanks, I got this part working. It is no beauty, but closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `div` `position: relative` and the `button` absolute, you can set the height to fill:

http://jsfiddle.net/hyXYJ/

Comment: This should work in bootstrap.  I would go with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

there is not enough information there, but here is an example.

if your container div has relative positioning, then you can apsolute position the button.
for example

```
div
{
position:relative;
}
button
{
position:absolute;
top:0;//it reach parent top
bottom:0;//it reach parent bottom
width:some width;
}
```

if you are using this approach, keep in mind the positioning of the other elements that are within the container div.

i've managed to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/T95wp/) with bootstrap included.  Take a look

Answer (score 1):

I am posting to show what I got with Alfred's changes.

[image: Won't win any design awards, but closer]

The modified code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>x-search-result</title>
    <link rel="components" href="packages/widget/components/collapse.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <element name="x-search-result" constructor="SearchResultComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div class="row-fluid" style="position:relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
          <span class="span10">
            <div class="accordion-heading" >
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">{{name}}</a>
            </div>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
          </span>
          <button class="btn offset10 span2" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0;" on-click="switchToCardView()">Go!</button>  
        </div>
        <script type="application/dart" src="xsearchresult.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
      </template>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might notice that I had to offset10 the button.